# Stop armv7s support in app update

Tags: ios, app-store, armv7

Previously, our iOS app supported armv6, armv7 and armv7s architectures. In the new version that is not submitted yet we added some third-party libraries that support armv6 and armv7 only. So the whole project was forced to support only these two architectures. I understand that armv7s is a superset of armv7 and compatibility won't be affected but is it ok to submit the update that doesn't support armv7s anymore to the App Store? Maybe someone had the same experience? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it may not helpful but I recommend that you should stop using non-supported 3rd party libraries, because at some point no more supported architecture remains which mutually supported by both the complier and your external library – and the compiler is the stronger one here defining the supported architectures, and if there is no common set, you will be in serious trouble.

Comment: Can you recompile the third-party library (i.e. do you have the source)?

Comment: @holex thanks for your answer, yes I understand that I should avoid supporting only old architectures because one day the compiler will drop it support. I'm planning to get sources of these 3rd party libraries but it could take some time.

Comment: @trojanfoe no, I don't have sources. Of course, re-compiling libraries could solve the problem. Or I can just try to manually create armv7s slice by duplicating armv7 one but this solution is quite jacky.

Comment: "jacky" would be a good word for doing that, yes.  However I don't know the answer to your question, so I would give it a try at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that excluding armv7s while still supporting armv7 doesn't affect on supported devices set, both submission and review process were successful.